# How do I find out the IP Address for all print jobs to a printer

Tags: ip, network-printer

Our network printer is spitting out unwanted print jobs which no one seems to collect. I want to know from which machine the jobs comes to the printer.
We have PaperCut in our server but these specific jobs are printing without any entry in Papercut.

Comment: The Printer (Kyocera Taskalfa7500) does come with a recent job list, but the user info is left blank. All it tells is the time it started and ended printing and a document name (doc2134xxx12)

Comment: If someone is able to send print jobs to the printer and PaperCut is installed on your server then that suggests the computer that is creating the print jobs does not have the PaperCut service installed or running. Have you ruled out someone printing from a rogue computer?

Comment: put a computer with 2 network cards in front of the printer and log the traffic - or use a passive hub and sniff the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Check the printer integrated log on the admin web interface, if your printer come with a log viewer.

**Edited**: As your printer does not have a log viewer, please use network monitor like wireshark to capture the packet from where they come. You can put a mirror port on your switch to capture or you can use a old hub, plugged in your printer and on a laptop to capture the packet.

The setup would look that way:

```
[switch] ----- [hub] ---- printer 
                     ---- laptop
```

After the packet capture, please check your DHCP to find some detail about who print.

A guide for wireshark [there](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/)

Comment: Printer does have a log viewer but it only says socument name(doc0213xx)and accepted time for the print job. the rest of the feilds are blank.

Comment: @vinayakvijayan Will update my answer, as you will have to capture some data manually

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an open question depending on your network... but some kind of network traffic monitoring might be useful... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_traffic_measurement

What kind of printer is it?  There may be a function to print out the IP address of the sender, or better yet, print recent logs.  You might need to enable logging first: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-printer-logs-54952.html

Is your printer and/or network behind a firewall?  There are almost certainly firewall logs on your network... but that all depends on your network...

Alternatively, you could try unplugging the printer and pluggin a laptop, with fixed IP the same as the printer's (if your network allows this).  Then you can monitor IP-based requests directly.  (not a great idea, but probably one that I would try just for fun and if nothing else works).  This might help if you're on a windows system: apparently I need more reputation to paste this link... google "nextofwindows tracking firewall activity with a windows 8 firewall log"

Let us know:

1) Printer model
2) Network type
3) Firewall status

Maybe we can help more?

Good luck!

Comment: These are all valid relevant points. Are you trying to answer the question or asking for more info?

Comment: Printer Model-Kyocera Taskalfa, Network Type-LAN with both DNS and DHCP. Windows 2012 server, No Firewall between the printer and network and yes the network is behind a firewall but i dont have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

How are jobs submitted not through Papercut? If possible you could force authentication and then you would be able to see who submitted via the accounting interface.